# Three-times vs three times

Tags: hyphenation

> Three times as many cases of measles were reported in the United States in 2014.

vs.

> Three-times as many cases of measles were reported in the United States in 2014.

Is there a difference between the normal and hyphenated versions? Which one is correct?

Comment: Handy rule: if unsure about needing a hyphen, you don't need it. Here, the hyphen would turn *three times* into an adjective ... when you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

Yosef Baskin commented:

> Handy rule: if unsure about needing a hyphen, you don't need it. Here, the hyphen would turn *three times* into an adjective ... when you don't need it.